# using annotations with spring to access webservice

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf

I need to access a `webservice` by using spring `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean`. i can wire it in a context xml and use it. are there any way to use that 'webservice' with only using annotations? i am using apache cxf and spring mvc 3.

baseline is i need to access a webservice without using xml configurations.is this possible?
i saw some annotations like `@WebMethod` and `@WebMethod` but i don't know how to use it properly.

can anyone pointed me to an example. appreciate your help.

my WS url - http://localhost:8080/test.asmx/HelloWorld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. please refer below.

```
JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean();
String URI = "http://localhost:8080/service";
try {

    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setWsdlDocumentUrl(new URL(URI+"?wsdl"));
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(myIService.class);
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setPortName(PORT);
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setNamespaceUri(URI);
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME);
    logger.debug("WSDL - "+jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.getWsdlDocumentUrl());
    jaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error occured while connecting to the TW web service -",e);
}
```

Please refer [Accessing web services using JAX-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html) to get more information about the port and URI.

Service Interface -

```
     public interface testService {
@WebMethod(operationName = "myOperations",  action = "")
@WebResult(name = "errorCode",targetNamespace = "")

public String testWebService(
    @WebParam(name = "studentId", targetNamespace = "", mode = Mode.IN) Integer studentId,
    @WebParam(name = "studenName", targetNamespace = "", mode = Mode.IN) String studenName);
    }
```

myOperations - is the operation that you need to access in the webService

errorCode - is the return value from the webservice

studentId , studentName - are the parameters that you need to send to the webservice.

I got stuck how to figure out to map more than one attribute as webResults. I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823506/spring-3-web-service-interface-mapping-issue-with-wsdl) question and still didn't have any luck.